# Remote Debugging with Tomcat and Eclipse - What could be the issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have Tomcat 7 running in my local machine. I deployed a War file and it works fine.
I am trying to debug this application from eclipse.

I set the following in `startup.bat` file:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

When I run the `startup.bat` file from command line, it opens another window and starts tomcat. In the first line I see that debugger is getting started on the port 8000 (something like dt_xxx port 8000). So I can confirm the debugger is started.

I configured Eclipse Remote debugging in the debug configuration and attached source for the war file deployed (selected the project). Gave the port and servername (localhost:8000).

Set a breakpoint in the Servlet which is called from the browser. When I open the URL, I don't see anything happening in eclipse (I expected it to hit the breakpoint).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you see anything in the console about the debugger connecting?  If I recall correctly, a message is typically displayed.  You also should have some indication in eclipse to verify that the debugger is at least attached.

Comment: I clicked on Debug -> <My Debug Configuration>. I dont see anything. No error, no message.

Comment: Did you compile using the debug flag? If you're using Ant you set the `debug` tag to true.

Comment: Its Maven. Anything else I need to do?